# makefile: using for and ifneq

Tags: bash, makefile, sh

I have an objective in my makefile named "cambios" that makes a cvs commit on each file of the project (by separate) and shows the last revision.

Now, I have an auxiliar shellscript that do that, but I'd like to know how I can do it in the makefile. I've created the objective cambios2 that do the same without the auxiliar shellscript, but it has some syntax problems.

makefile:

```
(...)
TODO= makefile cambiosaux.sh lib/libreria.cc include/libreria.h src/principal.cc
(...)

cambios: 
    @./cambiosaux.sh "$(TODO)" 

cambios2:
    @for dir in $(TODO); do \
         A = $(cvs commit -m "Incorporando cambios automáticamente." $$dir) \
         ifneq ($(A),)
            echo $dir ; \
            echo "Última revisión:"$(echo $(A) | sed 's/.*new revision: //' | sed 's/;.*//') ; \
         endif  ; \                                             
    done
```

cambiosaux.sh :

```
for dir in $1
do
    A=$(cvs commit -m "Incorporando cambios automáticamente." $dir)
    if [ "$A" != "" ]; then
        echo $dir
        echo "Última revisión:"$(echo $A | sed 's/.*new revision: //' | sed 's/;.*//')
    fi
done
```

There are some syntax problems in the objective cambios2, but I'm really new on doing makefiles and I really don't know how to solve that problems.

Thanks!

Comment: You're thinking too much. The commands for a Makefile rule *are* to be in sh. Just copypaste the contents of aux.sh into the MF.

Comment: I've tried it, but it's not working cause it's not the same syntax...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the way it works:

```
CVS: $(TODO)
    @for dir in $?; do \
    echo $$dir ; \
        echo "Última revisión:" $$(cvs commit -m "Incorporando cambios automáticamente." $$dir | grep "new revision" |  sed 's/.*new revision: //' | sed 's/;.*//') ; \
    done

cambios: CVS
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to escape dollars that are parts of Bash command command substitution, and Make tries to perform variable expansion: `$(cvs commit ...)`, `$(echo $(A) ...)`.

Also you can't assign a Make variable inside a recipe. `A = $(cvs commit ...)` is illegal, it won't be treated neither as Make assignment nor as Bash. Try to run `make` with `--warn-undefined-variables`, I guess it will say lots of interesting details.

Finally `ifneq` conditional is part of Make language, and it gets interpreted at the very early stage of reading Makefile. Thus you must not indent `ifneq` and `endif` with tabs. [How Make reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles) chapter gives a good explanation.

To conclude, I would recommend you to leave a separate `sh` as is and just invoke it from your Makefile. It is not good practice to mix code in two different languages.